# Is this a FSK signal?

Tags: fsk, signal-identification

I captured a signal on 433 MHz but I'm not able to build a functioning decoder for it. Is the transmitter using FSK to modulate the signal?

Sample: https://ufile.io/w9vismfu (250k, unsigned 8-bit IQ)

Comment: Hello Jonas and welcome to DSP SE. Your question seems to lack information. You should be a bit more specific as to what is the signal you captured, how did you capture it, how does it look like, etc. for people to be able to provide some help. Additionally, providing links that lead to downloadable content of disputable quality is not encouraged.

Comment: agree with ZaellixA, please provide an overall plot over a longer period of a complete message as well as zoomed in plots of your waveform on the scale of a few modulation symbols and we may be able to help determine from that.  Also indicate more details on what you have already tried to demodulate it. Thanks and welcome!